# Artifact feed python twine doesnt find it

Tags: python, azure-devops, feed, twine

I am using Artifacts feeds of Dev Ops for python package distribution, I used my default feed precrated inside artifacts of my own "Organization" and I can upload by "twine" python tool (a package) but not in the feed created by me ( not default). I have to create the feed because I want to do it the same in my employer organization and there is no default feed bacuase there are a lot projects and so. when I try to upload to created feed (Not deafult) to Dev Ops through twine function tells me that it doesnt exist. I am absolutely sure it exist and you can see it in the images, and if I try to do it in my employer dev ops organization it happen the same.

[Twine error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kp0xf.png)

[Exisitig Feed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RYmJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

> Artifact feed python twine doesnt find it

This is a know issue about the [Project-scoped feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2019/sprint-160-update#create-project-scoped-feeds-from-the-portal).

Microsoft recently **changed the default scope level for new feeds to Project instead of Organization**, which broke several Azure Pipeline tasks. Older feeds don't to be affected by this issue.

Check [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/833991/azure-pipelines-universal-packages-task-doesnt-run.html):

> New feeds are now by default project-scoped and a required fix for the
>   pipeline tasks failed to get deployed. We are **pushing out a hotfix to
>   update to the newest pipeline task versions and it should be out by
>   the end of the day**.

So, the easiest solution is to use the old feed.

Hope this helps.